# Is this CPU usage normal for Xorg?

Tags: compiz, xorg, cpu-load

I checked System Monitor to see if the frequency of my CPU increases without doing anything and saw that `xorg` is always using 10-40% of the CPU even if it's not doing much of anything on the desktop or simply surfing the Internet. Is this normal? If not, how can I fix it?

I have:

- a Macbook white 4,1
- Core2 Duo running at 2.10 GHz
- GPU Intel GMA X3100
- 4GB of RAM
- Ubuntu 11.04

I am running Unity and I do not have many effects enabled. I have only activated Compiz animations, scale, desktop, some shadows...

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the System Monitor itself is a rather graphics intensive application, which makes your claim of not doing anything slightly odd. Try running 'top' instead, but ultimately, xorg will probably use less cpu if compiz is off.

Comment: +1 - System Monitor uses a fairly large amount of resources and will likely skew your results.

Comment: No matter how intensive System Monitor is, having xorg taking up 10-40% of the cpu is not normal at all. My - although more powerful by a rather noticeable difference - system has never seen xorg use more than 2-3%. Right now, for example, Xorg sits between 0 and 1 %.

Answer (score 0):

40% doesn't seem to be normal. However, how you are measuring this? Are you using top command? Can you also check the output of vmstat command and see how much cpu utilization?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/803943?comments=all

It is the most annoying thing in Precise and everyone is waiting for a fix...