# Compiz using 8% - 25% CPU continually

Tags: compiz, cpu-load, multi-core

Any tips?

- Intel Core 2 Quad x64
- Ubuntu precise 12.04
- Dell OptiPlex 760
- nvidia graphics driver

Comment: Same problem here... Dell Precision, dual core, NVidia graphics card.

Comment: @JosuhaRountree I know what you mean. I think you should give Ubuntu another chance. Just don't use anything above `11.04`. Get `9.10` or something and if you want to use `11.04` or `11.10` make sure that you get `gnome-panel` which is the closest thing to gnome 2 and significantly reduces the grief of compiz. I use Ubuntu `11.10` with `gnome-panel`. I am a mathematical programmer and with this config I end up using only 500MB which is 1/16th of my RAM.

Comment: Why didn't you just use another distro?

Answer (score 30):

I also had compiz constantly taking around 10-12% CPU. I installed `ccsm` using

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

launched CCSM and under the OpenGL unticked sync to vblank. Now compiz is only taking up 2-4% CPU.

[This website](http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/) also suggests setting **Texture Filter** to **fast**.

Comment: works fine for me with an ati 7950

Comment: Any idea why this works?

Comment: Also [documented here](http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/) which additionally suggests to change the "Texture Filter" from "Good" to "Fast".

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: After the vsync setting I turn off window shadow where I can, and some same decorations. After that compiz use 1.4-3%

Comment: This worked but then I noticed high compiz cpu use when watching videos on google chrome. Watching in full screen fixes the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same problem. Compiz constantly at around 40% (AMD CPU, ATI 58xx, 12.04). Then i followed the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/127310/26508) and CPU utilization dropped below 10%. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For me in 12.10, removing the compiz settings on `~/.compiz` and rebooting solved the problem. I just renamed the folder, it might help if you want to recover your settings after all.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to help with Ubuntu 12.04 x64 on a T61 with NVIDIA GPU was unticking sync to VBlank in ccsm OpenGL settings. Sync to vblank is already enabled in nvidia-settings so there's no vertical tearing or such.