# Nvidia xorg.conf options for better performances in Unity 3d

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz

I am on precise, unity works fine but I would like to improve the performances of the system. The dash, for example, is slow and has an high cpu usage. Compiz in general uses 3-4% of cpu, and this is quite annoying for a notebook. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Take the following steps for better performance:

1. Open `compizconfig-settings-manager`. Go to OPENGL section. uncheck **Sync To VBlank**
2. Add `vm.swappiness=$VALUE` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` file by executing

   ```
   echo "vm.swappiness=10" |sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf > /dev/null
   ```
3. Use swap. If you don't have, create using [this tutorial](http://shantanucse.blogspot.com/2012/07/create-swap-after-ubuntu-installation.html).
4. Again compiz-settings-manager. Go to Unity plugin > Experimental section. Change Dash bar to **static blur**
5. Avoid left click on dash. Use right click for specific option.
6. If you have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file (do not create it if you do not have one),  add the following lines in Device section

   ```
   Option "AccelMethod" "EXA"
   Option "MigrationHeuristic" "greedy"
   Option "AccelDFS" "true"
   Option "EnablePageFlip" "true"
   Option "EnableDepthMoves" "true"
   ```

Comment: Why code tag is not working :( ?

Comment: You need to indent it with an additional four spaces if you are using it in an enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually quite good for compiz on nvidia, as it can be much higher.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128649/compiz-using-8-25-cpu-continually-in-precise-12-04) thread for more information on the problem.