# Xorg and compiz using 20% of CPU

Tags: 12.10, compiz, xorg, cpu

I'm not doing anything in particular but Xorg is currently using 8-15% of my CPU and Compiz is using 5-15% as well. I have 4 virtual desktops (aka workspaces) and like 10 windows open but I see no reason why it should be using this much cpu.

I'm using 12.10 on a Asus UX31a, does anybody have hints to lower the cpu usage?

Comment: Crying that Xorg and compiz with 4 virtual desktops and 10 windows open is like crying that Porsche Cayenne burns 20 liters of petrol for 100 km [; But seriously, if you want better  perfomence, consider switching to other desktop environment. Start from here: http://scriptevolution.com/blog/2012/08/top-10-ubuntu-desktop-environments-and-shells/

Comment: +1 for the link to a *very* nice (optically pleasing and informative) page!

Comment: I agree that 20 % seems "high" (esp. on state-of-the-art hardware) and might be an indication that there's still a lot of slack in your current configuration -- or that there's some "bug" beneath it. There's very likely a lot of fine-tuning, tweaking and optimizing you can do on your "Porsche" (to quote ***Melon***), e.g. with CCSM or Ubuntu Tweak dot com or manually with gconf-editor or dconf-editor... details of which are covered in ample detail in other Q&A's.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/HighCPU

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!