# Compiz at 30% of CPU on Thinkpad T420

Tags: compiz, 13.10, lenovo

After upgrading to 13.10, the compiz process has started taking 30% or more of CPU resources.  In addition unity is sluggish and steam games that worked fine under 13.04 have a very low frame rate and are unplayable.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many compiz config tweaks found under other answers, I looked at dmesg and found the following:

```
[ 36.361815] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307 
[ 36.361818] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues. 
[ 36.361819] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this. –
```

Looking at Lenovo's site: [Lenovo support for T420](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-77167) There was a bios upgrade available for my machine released on the 17th of July, 2013. After running this update, the video works as in 13.04.

Comment: any advice how to install the bios update without any windows?

Comment: http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/83uj28us.iso is a bootable CD.

Comment: I get the same message `Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307` on my X220, but even after the update the latest `1.39` BIOS it does not go away (Ubuntu 13.10).