# Compiz using 40% CPU on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: compiz, 13.10

After upgrading to 13.10, `compiz` process has started taking up to 40% of CPU resources. In addition, Unity is sluggish just like in this recent question [Compiz at 30% of CPU on Thinkpad T420](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365534/compiz-at-30-of-cpu-on-thinkpad-t420). My PC is HP Compaq NX6310 and Compiz version is 0.9.10.2. First I had error message during boot, but did find solution for that ([Bug #1014289](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1014289)) by updating the kernel to newer 3.11.4, it did not change the CPU usage. For the CPU problem I tried solution for [Bug #1221837](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221837) by adding the line `MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=1.4`
in the file `/etc/environment` - that did not help me, so my problem seems not to be the same bug. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 3):

The high CPU use could be due to fallback to the software renderer. You can verify whether or not you're using the software renderer by executing the following command on the command-line:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

If the result is as follows:

```
Not software rendered:    no
```

That indicates that the software renderer is being used (nice use of a double negative there). In that case, installing the [latest version of the Intel graphics drivers](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux), as recommended in another comment, should help. However, as of November 28, Ubuntu 13.10 is not yet supported by the Installer. It appears to be one of those "any time now" situations.

In the meantime, I was able to fix the problem on my system (ThinkPad T420S) by installing the drivers via the [oibaf ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers/) which supports Ubuntu 13.10. unity_support_test now verifies that software rendering is disabled. Hope this helps and let us know if you managed to fix the issue, as well.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libg3dvl-mesa` Then add the driver to xorg: `echo "/usr/lib/dri/libXvMCr600.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/X11/XvMCConfig`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your graphics driver with the Intel Graphics Updater [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is still one problem - I can't install the driver because it claims libpackagekit-glib2.so.14 is missing and it cannot be resolved. I have to wait for the libpackagekit-glib2.so update as said in https://01.org/linuxgraphics/node/238.