# Compiz using high CPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiz

I'm running 
`Ubuntu Desktop 13.10` with `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)`

I've tried installing the:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

I've tried the http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/ thing.

But it still uses over 50% of the CPU.. Do someone know of a driver or fix for my problem? Can't find any driver for this specific nvidia card..

The solutions above are from other askubuntu questions.

### Update:

Additional information:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p

OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.3.0 NVIDIA 304.88

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Also did the `unity_supported_test -c -p`

```
Compiz supported:         yes
```

Should some of these be no?

Comment: Maybe follow suggestions here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369033/compiz-using-40-cpu-on-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: Did that now, it's not the case. My "Not software render:" is set to "yes".

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem. I installed gnome-shell environment and dropped Unity.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Then logged out and chose GNOME

[image: Choosing GNOME instead of Ubuntu]

This removed the `compize` process from my `$top` list and replaced it with `Xorg` and `gnome-shell` (not sure if Xorg were on the list previous to the change of desktop envirement). These two processes average about 5% of the CPU combined.