# Ubuntu 14.04 Compiz taking lot of CPU resources

Tags: 14.04, compiz, intel-graphics

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop on a virtual machine with 1.5 GB of RAM and 20GB hard-drive. The graphics card I have is "Intel Graphics HD 3000".

Some posts suggested to install the graphics driver

```
intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.4-0intel1_amd64.deb
```

I did that but still compiz is taking lot of CPU and the machine is very slow. Please suggest a remedy. 
I was pretty comfortable with 12.04 LTS and if it's some known issue with 14.04, I'll revert to 12.04 LTS.

Thanks,

Comment: This bug affects me too. I'd like to encourage everyone to login on this page: https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1293384 Here you can find "This bug affects NN people" (27 persons at this moment including me). Please mark there that it does affect you too and subscribe to receive messages about this bug. It might help to solve it sooner (each affected person and each subscriber increases "bug heat" value).

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!

Comment: According to this page, it's the video driver:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2271938

Answer (score 9):

It is a official bug.
Compiz CPU usage dramatically increased in Ubuntu 14.04 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1293384
Very high cpu usage for compiz in 14.04 (mesa incorrectly using llvmpipe) 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1268146