# Ubuntu 14.04 running very slow after upgrade 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit to 64 bit. I find right after I boot it the first time that the machine is running really slow, even slower than when I had the 32 bit version.

I find that when I run `top` command, the `compiz` process is occupying 90% of the CPU. I tried to resolve that somehow, but no success yet. I also saw a message from the system saying that 3D at this time is being done in software and X is not using hardware acceleration to achieve it.

I want to ask if someone else also faced this issue, and how could I bring my machine up to speed.

I have i7 processor with 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: Could you add output of `sudo lshw -c display` to the question.

Comment: I am facing same issue, I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit to 64 bit. I using 4GB of Ram and I5 processor, when I type free -m command shows free 288mb and used 3465mb and 
$> sudo lshw -c display


  description: VGA compatible controller
  product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 2
  bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
  configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

Answer (score 0):

see the post for ubuntu 12.04 and solving memory issues with compiz

[Compiz using 8% - 25% cpu continually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128649/compiz-using-8-25-cpu-continually)

most of the fixes are backup/delete setting file or changing compiz settings

Answer (score -2):

For 64 bit O.S you must have more than 4GB RAM, in other case will be very Slow !!! I had the same problem, finally reinstalled 32 bits and my laptop is fast again.

Comment: read carefully..the OP said he has 16GB