# Compiz cpu usage too high after update

Tags: compiz, cpu-load

I started using Ubuntu 14.04 and i had no problems with high cpu usage and watching videos, but after the recent update to 14.10 when i play a video on my file system .avi or .mp4 doesn't matter the file type, my pc starts lagging like crazy. When i write top in the terminal it says that vlc media player is using 185% of the cpu and compiz is using 125% of the cpu. As soon as i close the media player (every video player lags) my cpu usage goes down to about 30% and everything is normal. I updated my flash player and i ma using the optimal drivers for my nvidia video card. Watching videos in youtube also causes my cpu to go crazy but the playback does not lag.

Comment: Play the videos using a different player and check the CPU usage.

Comment: Same. Any video player makes the cpu usage go crazy. I had to install Sm player just now because for some reason if i open it with the default video player i get sent back to the login screen.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here on 14.04 itself:  Since a recent update, all video players cause compiz to go over 100% cpu.  Even  VLC in paused state will cause this.

Comment: i found a solution to this problem in my case. I have a built in intel video card and apparently the update deleted my video drivers. In system info it used to say baciz or something like that instead of intel for my video card info. After i reinstalled my intel video drivers everything fixed.

Comment: A working solution is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/162913/5786) - I hope it helps you as much as it helped me!